# Clang front end: keeping track reads and writes of a statement

Tags: c, clang, frontend, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writting a small tool using `clang libTooling` and I would like to keep track of function variables reads and writes. I can do this for simple statements of the form `int x = 4;` or `d = x + y;` using `ASTMatchers`. Now consider this function:

```
void fun(int *ptr) {
    int x = 20;
    int i = 2;
    ptr[++i] = x + 45;   //line 4 and assuming ++i is a valid index
    //line 4: Reads{i, x} and writes{ptr, i} 
}
```

Line 4 of the `AST` would translate to:

```
  | `-BinaryOperator 0x7fa5011dad78 <line:10:5, col:20> 'int' '='
  |   |-ArraySubscriptExpr 0x7fa5011dacc8 <col:5, col:12> '__global int' lvalue
  |   | |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fa5011dacb0 <col:5> '__global int *' <LValueToRValue>
  |   | | `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fa5011dac40 <col:5> '__global int *' lvalue ParmVar 0x7fa5011da238 'ptr' '__global int *'
  |   | `-UnaryOperator 0x7fa5011dac90 <col:9, col:11> 'int' prefix '++'
  |   |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fa5011dac68 <col:11> 'int' lvalue Var 0x7fa5011daba8 'i' 'int'
  |   `-BinaryOperator 0x7fa5011dad50 <col:16, col:20> 'int' '+'
  |     |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fa5011dad38 <col:16> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
  |     | `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fa5011dacf0 <col:16> 'int' lvalue Var 0x7fa5011daaf8 'x' 'int'
  |     `-IntegerLiteral 0x7fa5011dad18 <col:20> 'int' 45
```

The question is straightforward, is there a way to keep track of all the reads/writes at each line? It wouldn't be feasible to try an `ASTMatcher`of each of all the potential different expression forms. The actual problem is that I don't really know all the different nested forms of nested expressions. Is there a tool or a method for that ?

Comment: A debugger watch?

Comment: @MartinJames It looks like they are asking how to statically track all possible reads and writes from the AST. A debugger watch would require the program to be executed and only track the reads/writes observed during a single execution.

Comment: I did something similar. Most writes can be found on the left hand side of an assignment operator and in prefix/postfix operators. Most reads can be found on the right hand side of assignment operators, function call arguments, and object member accesses (f.a() reads f). This method worked ok for me and getting anything more detailed requires some pretty heavy static analysis. Does O.foo(int &a, int *b) modify O, a, or b? It's very hard to tell from the AST alone. Even that is fairly tame considering everything that is possible in C++. TL;DR: finding all reads and writes from AST is hard.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic it is for a research project I am doing and ultimately I want to track all the reads and writes of `OpenCL kernels -- its syntax is a subset of C so no fancy classes etc`. That's what I am doing now, I am tracking the LHS but the combinations are countless. I am searching for an algorithm/method such that can work on `every` situation. The simplest method I could think of is check the `OpenCL kernel specification` and write a matcher for every possible combination but I don't think that this would be optimal.

Comment: @MartinJames I want static analysis.

Comment: yes, this is very hard esp. if you want to take pointers into account and get an answer which is better than "modified some integer somewhere".  It is a huge effort to do this and you need to go way beyond the AST to do it accurately.  (This is from personal experience: my company does this for C++ but not with Clang.)

Comment: @IraBaxter There is way but it's cumbersome. You can follow the specification of the language, in my case, OpenCL and implement ASTMatchers for each part of the specification. However, I am searching for a more "elegant" solution...

Comment: You'll discover that trying to interpret the language specification (let alone defining the AST matchers, which aren't enough to compute dataflow sensibly) will essentially turn into a giant task.   Our experience with extremely savvy C++ engineers and very strong infrastructure *designed* to support this task is that this effort takes about a man-decade.   Maybe you can do it faster.   I very much doubt it.   I suggest you find a solution where this has been done for you.